Why can't I solve this problem using binomial probability?

Draw $5$ random marbles from a box containing $10$ red marbles and $20$ blue marbles. What is the probability of getting $3$ red marbles and $2$ blue marbles?

Choosing $3$ red marbles from $10$ marbles is $\binom{10}{3}.$ Choosing $2$ marbles from $20$ blue marbles is $\binom{20}{2}.$ Choosing $5$ marbles from $30$ marbles is $\binom{30}{5}.$ So the probability is $P = \frac{\binom{10}{3}\binom{20}{3}}{\binom{30}{5}}.$
However, today I read about the binomial probabilities and wondered why it doesn't work for the same problem.
The probability of picking a red marble is $\frac{10}{30}.$ The probability of picking a blue marble is $\frac{20}{30}.$ We may pick them in different order so the probability of picking a total of $3$ red marbles and $2$ blue marbles is just the sum of all the probabilities of these sequences containing $3$ red marbles and $2$ blue marbles. Each probability is $(\frac{10}{30})^3(\frac{20}{30})^2,$ and there are $\binom{5}{3}$ such sequences, so the final probability is $\binom{5}{3}(\frac{10}{30})^3(\frac{20}{30})^2.$ I asked Copilot and it explained in circles that it's because in the original problem, I'm supposed to pick five marbles at once while the second solution suggests a sequential selection. I'm not quite convinced as I might as well pick the marbles in sequence totaling to 5 instead of grabbing all 5 marbles at once and it should be the same probability.
What's the difference between two solutions?
Thank you!

This is because when using "binomial probabilities" it is assumed that the probability of picking a success/failure is the same after each choice. In your example, once you pick a red ball, the chances of picking another red ball changes.

@NicolasBourbaki Ooo I get it!!! Thank you so so much!

To further add to your example, if you change the wording of the problem to replace the red/blue ball back into the box, then you can use binomial probability.

@NicolasBourbaki I see! Can't thank you enough!! I should have asked here earlier instead of arguing with Copilot for 30 mins ><.

Choosing $2$ marbles from $20$ blue marbles is $\displaystyle \binom{20}{\color{red}{2}}.$

@user2661923 Thanks for pointing that out! I just edited the post!
